# Drupal - Taxonomy page (show all terms of vocabulary)

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, taxonomy

I am kind of new to drupal (version 7).
I have taxonomy vocabulary with terms.

**Example structure:**

**Taxonomy vocabulary:** Address list
**Terms:**
Address 1
Address 2
Address 3

How can i create page with all these terms for this taxonomy vocabulary? Even if term is not associated with any of content?

Basically i need an page, that collects all terms from Taxonomy vocabulary called Address list and shows all terms that are created for this taxonomy vocabulary.

I know in drupal there are always many ways how to create things. I need most simple, without hardcoding.

I don't need full solution - any good road/idea/advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. Add new view & select **Taxonomy terms** of Type **Address list**.